# Annihilate Periodicity of a former activity [ANDROID]

Tags: android

I have been searching for a while a solution to my problem : I have two activities. The first one disappears to let the second one appears after 4 seconds.The problem is every 4 seconds the second activity is relaunched and so my application on my Smart phone is not stable at all (every 4 seconds the second activities appears, then disappears again and again !)

My aim is : after 4 seconds my first activity let place to the second one and the second must stay stable until an action of the user. How can I stop this "periodicity" ?

Here is the code of the two Java file : The first class =

```
public class MainActivityWelcome extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int TIME_OUT = 4000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_welcome);

        TextView texteView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notick);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/USAAF_Stencil.ttf");
        texteView.setTypeface(font);

        texteView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.notick)));

        final View myLayout = findViewById(R.id.notick);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityWelcome.this,FirstConnexion.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, TIME_OUT);
    }    
}
```

And the second class :

```
public class FirstConnexion extends MainActivityWelcome{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_connexion);
        TextView texteView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titlenotick);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/USAAF_Stencil.ttf");
        texteView1.setTypeface(font);

        texteView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.notick)));

    }

}
```

Do you know where I must play to stop this phenomenon ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

you are extending `MainActivityWelcome` to your `FirstConnexion`  that is why `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` again calling `MainActivityWelcome`'s `onCreate` method and it is again calling your `FirstConnexion` after 4 seconds . ***Result Infinite Call***

so you have to extend your `FirstConnexion` with `AppCompatActivity`

```
public class FirstConnexion extends AppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

public class FirstConnexion extends AppCompatActivity{

}